# How to string two numbers together with extra zeros

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, padding, number-formatting

How can I make a cell A1 "1234" with cell A2 "27" to make 12340027 as a number not text. In short, numbers in A2 are 1, 2 or 3 digits in length but they must be formatted to 4 digits e.g. 27= 0027, 4=0004. Using TEXT is resulting in lookup functions not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your formula in `VALUE()` to turn the text back to a number:

```
=VALUE(A1 & TEXT(A2,"0000"))
```

Or multiply the text by one (or add zero):

```
=(A1 & TEXT(A2,"0000"))*1
```

Comment: Your second suggestion of multiplying by 1 resulted in the extra zeroes being removed

Comment: Can't check at the moment. Could've sworn it worked by creating the number as text & then forcing a calculation on it. Have you got the *1 outside the last bracket?

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
=A1*10^4+A2
```

Just adds 4 zeros to the end of A1 and then adds A2 to it.

Answer (score 2):

@keatz also elegant answer

If I got you correctly, 
you can achieve it by this formula:

=CONCATENATE(A2,RIGHT(B2/10000,4))*1

[image]